# Set a variable as the ID of a clicked div, then modify that variable to select a different div

Tags: replace, attributes, onclick

I have multiple images and when I click on one I want the code to set that specific images ID (`"image_select_1"`) as a variable. I then want to modify that variable by removing the text `"select"` (with underscores on either side of it) from the middle of it so the variable becomes `"image1"`. Then use that variable to target a different `DIV` and fade it in. Here the is the code I have however it's of course, not working.

```
        var foo;
        $('.game_selection_image').click(function() {
            foo = $(this).attr("id");
            foo = foo.replace("_select_","");
            $("#" + foo).fadeIn(500);
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch your variables

```
$("div.game_selection_image").click(function(e) {
    var foo = $(this).attr("id");
    foo = foo.replace("_select_","");
    $('#' + foo).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: I actually just figured that out, however it still isn't working. When I 

                window.alert( foo )

 before the fade in, it has the correct name but it still doesn't fade in.

Comment: EDIT: It works, I need to sleep I keep making silly mistakes; Thank you :D